# Code crashes. While pass c char array to function which catch with std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

Code  crashes While pass c char array (i.e `data_info.user_name` in my case) to function which catch with `std::string`.

Core get generated when calling `SendClient()`. I suspect this is because of the data being passed i.e `data_info.user_name` (char array)
not sure about the root cause. Can anyone please point at the error.

```
void DataProcessingImpl::onUpdate(const DB_DATA_INFO& data_info) {
  std::vector<DataProcessingImpl*>::iterator iter = observer.begin();
  for (; iter != observer.end(); ++iter)
    (*iter)->SendClient(data_info.user_name); // This line core is generated
  }
```

**GDB BT :**

```
0x0000001254dergfd in void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<std::__1::__bind<void (UserInfo::DataProvider::*)(DB_DATA const&), UserInfo::DataProvider*, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1>&>&, DB_DATA const&>(std::__1::__bind<void (UserInfo::DataProvider::*)(DB_DATA const&), UserInfo::DataProvider*, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1>&>&, DB_DATA const&) () from
```

**Definition of DB_DATA_INFO**

```
#define LEN 23
typedef struct DB_DATA
{
    char user_name[24];

    DB_DATA() : user_name("") {}
    DB_DATA(const DB_DATA& value) : user_name("") {
        std::strncpy(user_name, value.user_name, LEN);
        }
    DB_DATA(const char* value) : user_name("")
    {
        if (value == nullptr)
        {
            std::memset(user_name, 0, sizeof user_name);
        }
        else
        {
            std::strncpy(user_name, value, LEN);
        }
    }
    DB_DATA(std::string value) : user_name("") {

        std::strncpy(user_name, value.c_str(), LEN);

    }

    DB_DATA& operator=(const DB_DATA &db_val)
    {
        std::strncpy(user_name, db_val.user_name, LEN);
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const char* db_val)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        if (db_val == nullptr)
        {
            ret = (std::strlen(user_name) == 0);
        }
        else
        {
            ret = (std::strncmp(user_name, db_val, LEN) == 0);
        }
    bool operator!=(const char* db_val)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        if (db_val == nullptr)
        {
            ret = !(std::strlen(user_name) == 0);
        }
        else
        {
            ret = !(std::strncmp(user_name, db_val, LEN) == 0);
        }
        return ret;
    }
     bool operator==(const DB_DATA& db_val) {
         return (std::strncmp(user_name, db_val.user_name, LEN) == 0);
         }
     bool operator!=(const DB_DATA& db_val) {
          return !(std::strncmp(user_name, db_val.user_name, LEN) == 0);
          }
} DB_DATA_INFO;
```

Comment: Why `user_name` has 24 bytes, when `LEN` is 25 ? Probably `user_name` doesn't have null terminator when string ctor is called reading this array.

Comment: @rafix07 sorry that was typo mistake LEN is 23 i have corrected it

Comment: You can avoid that with `char user_name[LEN+1];` - that way no matter what you define `LEN` to be `user_name` is always to correct length. (hint: avoid using *magic-numbers*)

Comment: You have a common misunderstanding about strncpy. strncpy **does not guarantee that's its output is null terminated**. You might think this is crazy, and you'd be right, but it is true. Read the definition of [strncpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) carefully. You have to add the terminator yourself, or better still use a sensibly defined function.

Comment: The error is - `std::strncpy(user_name, value.user_name, LEN);` if there are `LEN` characters in the initializer. You need `LEN + 1`  in `strncpy` or `user_name` will NOT be nul-terminated because there is no nul-byte in the first `LEN` characters copied.

Comment: See the **Warning:** in [strcpy(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) in the `strncpy` description.

Comment: Avoid all these errors just using `std::string user_name`.

Comment: Don't use `define`s in c++ code, use `const` or `constexpr` values

Comment: Do not use typedef struct in C++ as you could simply use named struct. And do not use #define to create global constant value, use constexpr instead.